# Perl: Encoding binary number to base64

Tags: perl, binary, base64, encode

I have a string that is essentially binary

```
my $string = "000110";
```

I've been trying to use encode_base64 but that encodes strings, if im reading the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) correctly.

```
my $j = MIME::Base64->encode_base64($string);
print "$j\n"; # should print 'A'
>> TUlNRTo6QmFzZTY000000
```

How can I achive this in perl? the string is expected to be ~120 binary bits in length.
I'd rather not use any modules that are not installed with perl by default, the target audience for this script is not familiar with the shell.

Edit:
A lot of the answers to this question have been surrounded about strings, not actual numbers, there was one solution I found, but it required Math::BaseCalc module to be installed.

Edit2: Essentially, if i have

```
my $binary_string = "000110";
```

i would like to have it encoded in base64 (as a number), so it returns

```
>>G  # for this case (binary number 000110 to base64 number = G)
```

Comment: When you say "essentially binary" do you mean that it is actually binary?

Comment: yes, $string = "1001011" for example, so the string only has ones or zeros, each character of the string is to be a binary bit

Comment: so long as it takes the string and encodes it as a base64, but treats it as a number, not as a string as encode_base64 does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

base64 is an algorithm that converts strings of 8-bit bytes/characters. Anything else must be packed into bytes.

You already have a string, but you could be more space-efficient by packing the 120 bits into 15 bytes using the following:

```
my $base64 = encode_base64(pack("B*", $binary), "");
```

The inverse operation is

```
my $binary = unpack("B*", decode_base64($base64));
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -E'say encode_base64(pack("B*", $ARGV[0]), "")' \
   0100000101000010
QUI=

$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -E'say unpack("B*", decode_base64($ARGV[0]))' \
   QUI=
0100000101000010
```

---

If you have actually have a number of bits that's not divisible by 8, you can prefix the string with the number of bits.

```
my $base64 = encode_base64(pack("CB*", length($binary), $binary), "");
```

The inverse operation is

```
my ($length, $binary) = unpack("CB*", decode_base64($base64));
substr($binary, $length) = "";
```

Comment: `my $base64 = encode_base64 pack 'B*', "00000000";` returns `AA==` not `A`

Comment: @Yusuf Ali, Correct. And that's a good thing, because `A` is not valid base64.

Comment: i tried with `00000000`, which should return 'A', but doesnt

Comment: Not so. `A` is not valid base64.

Comment: u sure? http://alfredo4570.net/src/bases.html, i type `00000000` and it returns 'A'

Comment: Then it made an error. You require one character of output for each 6 bits of input, and there's padding at the end. Think of it this way: If 8 bits fit in one character, you wouldn't need base64 in the first place.

Comment: so 6 binary bits = 1 base 64 bit?

Comment: No. Again, `base64` is an algorithm that encodes a sequence of *bytes*. 3 bytes => 4 ASCII chars. (Padding is used to round up to a multiple of 3 bytes.)